# base64 decode - nul in string

Tags: string, r, base64, digest, rcurl

I'm trying to create function that will run private API calls on some sites.
All those sites are using authentication by signature of the API call as follows in php:

```
base64_encode( hash_hmac('sha512', $post_data, base64_decode($secret), true) )
```

Using package digest and RCurl I can easily write as:

```
base64Encode( hmac(key = base64Decode(secret), object = post_data, algo = 'sha512', raw = TRUE) )
```

I'm fighting whole day with the hmac **key** parameter input:

```
key = base64Decode(secret)
```

The issue is that hmac function accept only string value but base64Decode might return something more than just string:

```
str(base64Decode(secret))
chr "îă?ľÂÜĄ\vŽĺ\022""| __truncated__
```

This **__truncated__** is the key issue here. So the next thing I've tried was take a raw output from decode function and rawToChar on it:

```
str(base64Decode(secret,mode='raw'))
raw [1:64] ee e3 3f be ...

rawToChar(base64Decode(secret,mode='raw'))
```

> Error in rawToChar(base64Decode(secret,mode='raw')) : embedded nul in
>   string:
>   'îă?ľÂÜĄ\vŽĺ\022\0!^\026Č‹¶©wŚˇ0Î\035ë\026\r\001ňKÍ„Rř\003j„7¤Ň\nťä_\004m@ß\0Ă"c\0271˝ZnĚ55’v'

As we can see now, there is a mystery **nul** thing somewhere in my (not even yet) string. I don't care much about the nuls, I just need to pass this piece of data as input for hmac.

1. Is there any possibility to handle string with nul, just for pushing it farther as input upper function?
2. Is there any possibility to have hmac function **key** parameter accept raw object like this?

I tried also base64enc package with no success. I tried many many different conversions but everything is going back this simple 'nul in string'.

These sites are rather new and this authentication process looks like a standard API auth among them. There should be some way to handle that process in R.

If anyone want to test,

```
secret <- '7uM/vsLcpQuOmOUSACFeFsiLtql3jKEwzh3rFg0B8kvNhFL4A2qEN6TSCp3kXwRtQN8AwyJjFzG9Wm7MNTWSdg=='
```

Comment: I get the same problem. base64Decode truncates results when outputting to character for some reason...

Comment: @bumpkin use `raw` instead of `character`.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer for the question 2. is:

*hmac function already accept raw object instead of string.*

This is the solution:

```
hmac(key = base64Decode(secret, mode='raw'),
 object = post_data,
 algo = 'sha512',
 raw = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure that th `truncated` is the problem. When you apply `str` to your output, you ask it to display its structure. That's what it does :

```
chr "îă?ľÂÜĄ\vŽĺ\022""| __truncated__
```

`chr` means that the object is of class `character` (a string). `str` then displays the beginning of the string, put truncates its output. Hence the `truncated` displayed by `str`. If you want to display the complete string, just type its name or use `print` :

```
secret <- '7uM/vsLcpQuOmOUSACFeFsiLtql3jKEwzh3rFg0B8kvNhFL4A2qEN6TSCp3kXwRtQN8AwyJjFzG9Wm7MNTWSdg=='
str(base64Decode(secret))
# chr "\xee\xe3?\xbe\xc2ܥ\v\x8e\x98\xe5\022"
```

So I suppose that the problem is not with the `base64Decode` function, but elsewhere in your script.

Comment: This is not the whole string, passing it to hmac will produce different results. Can you please try the same base64decode in other tool, for example php. It will be different. Or you may just base64Decode as raw and make rawToChar on it, then you will see the whole string.

Comment: @MusX on my system, both R and php give the same results, in character or in binary mode...

Comment: can you please try `rawToChar(base64Decode(secret,mode='raw'))` and check what string it will try to return? as you can see in my post there is a bigger string in the error message, this bigger string is truncated exactly at the location where "\0" character is, if you google for "\0" you will find this is a **nul** character. And the string was truncated at the point where nul occured.