# R decode a column encoded with base64

Tags: r, base64

In R, I have a data frame with a column "content" encoded with base64. I can decode a single entry of "content" in the row 355 like below;

```
library(base64enc)
rawToChar(base64decode(df[355,"content"]))
```

When I try to decode with

```
rawToChar(base64decode(df$content))
```

I get the error "embedded nul in string". How can I decode the whole column?

Edit: I used a loop and it seems OK but I don't think that it is an elegant solution.

```
comments.decoded <- data.frame(comments=character(),
                               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for(i in 1:nrow(df))
{
    clean.row <- iconv(rawToChar(base64decode(df[i,"content"])), "latin1", "UTF-8")
    clean.row <- data.frame(trimws(clean.row), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    comments.decoded <- rbind(comments.decoded, clean.row)
}

comments.decoded
```

Comment: Can you make a minimal example? I can't reproduce your issue with `c("MQ==", "Mg==", "Mw==")` (1,2,3 in character)

Comment: Related, maybe duplicate post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964142/r-base64-decode-nul-in-string

Comment: @sebastian-c I cannot post an example, I obtained a csv file which I have to analyze and not share with anybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To [quote](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16445) one of the presidents of the R foundation:

> R hasn't supported embedded nulls in strings for quite a long time
>   [...] If you want bytes that contain nulls, don't store them in
>   character variables, store them in raw vectors

You might try

```
sapply(df$content, function(x) { 
  res <- try(rawToChar(base64decode(x) )) 
  if (!inherits(res, "try-error")) res else NA  
})
```

This yields `NA` for strings that contain `nul`.